Is It Better to Use 'a Staircase' or 'the Staircase' in This Example, and Why?
In the below example, which exists in the context of a piece of fiction writing (made up for this question), is it better to use 'a' (the indefinite article) or 'the' (the definite article) with 'staircase leading to the floor above'?
For further context, in this building, there's only one staircase that leads to the upper floor, and the main character (and the reader) are not familiar with the building in any way; they've only just encountered it.

In front of Jack was a large building. He entered through the front door and made his way toward a/the staircase leading to the floor above.

The reason I'm unsure is that I, the writer, know there's only one staircase that leads to the upper floor, but the reader doesn't. I don't want to give the impression there are other staircases elsewhere, but I also don't want to imply that the reader should know there's just one. The use of the reduced relative clause 'leading to the floor above' restricts the identity of the noun phrase, but I'm not sure if this is sufficient to identify it for the reader.
Any justification to explain your preference would be extremely helpful.

Such a well-formulated question!

If I could not describe better what Jack saw, for pacing reasons, I would write:

Before Jack was a large building. Entering through the front door he spotted a staircase on the left and took that to the second floor.

There is little point in saying "made his way" if there are no obstacles between him and the staircase, like benches or people wandering about, and you described none.
If you are not going to describe what Jack is seeing, make the transition to the next scene as brief as possible.
This construction leaves open the possibility of other staircases in the building, but Jack doesn't care. This one was all he needed. Typically multi-story buildings will have fire escape stairs behind labeled doors; an exposed staircase in a building lobby would most likely not be the only staircase.

This is good. Or "took the staircase he spotted on the left to the floor above." Of course, making one's way to isn't taking. Perhaps there's an interruption, such as someone stepped out from a doorway and trained a gun on him and said "this way, please."

@BobRodes Such an interruption or obstruction would have to be described, not implied, to render "made his way" better than just implying the mode of travel between the front door and the staircase by "took". Just "took the staircase" implies a direct walk to the staircase and then climbing it. Now, if we wrote that "entering through the front door, Jack was confronted by dozens of people standing and conversing in the lobby," Then following that with "...lobby, he made is way to the staircase he spotted on the left" would make sense. Without a description of the obstacles, it does not.

Yes, it would. I didn't mean to imply otherwise. Just that "making his way" would allow such an interruption. So yeah, you already covered that, now that I read your post again. :)

I would omit any mention of “spotting” a staircase because that hints at surprise.  Why not expect to find a staircase near a front door?

@AntonSherwood I disagree, "spotted' does not hint at surprise. It indicates "recognition" or "identification". Typically when one enters an unfamiliar building, we scan the scene to orient ourselves. If one does that right-left, one "spots" (identifies) the route to the higher floors. He might easily have spotted an elevator; but the stairs are a more immediate form of immediate action; I would have a stairway there for that literary purpose.

Protagonist

I, the writer, know there's only one staircase that leads to the upper
floor, but the reader doesn't.

The writer, and the reader, are not the protagonist. Jack is.
Jack is experiencing this. We are limited to Jack's 3rd-person POV. If he can't see another staircase, and he is not currently worried about an alternate staircase (which the person he is pursuing might use to escape), then narratively there is only one staircase.

Except there could be one in view that leads down, couldn't there?

This story is not written from the protagonist's perspective. This story is written from the narrator's perspective. Therefore, what matters is what the narrator describes, not what Jack's perspective is.

@BobRodes No, there cannot be another staircase in view, as the question clearly states that "there's only one staircase".

@Ben There's only one staircase that leads to the upper floor. But that means that there could be another staircase that leads elsewhere, or the same staircase going down. If he had said "there's only one staircase, which leads to the upper floor" then that possibility would be eliminated. At least, that's my understanding of restrictive vs. non-restrictive clauses.

@ZerGreenOne A narrator (unlike the author) need not be omniscient.

I lean towards "the," although I think either is fine. "The staircase that leads to the floor above" specifies a particular staircase, and thus implies the definite article. It also distinguishes the staircase from possible other staircases that lead elsewhere, such as one that leads to the basement.

If Jack hasn't entered the building before and hasn't seen the staircase before, the correct word(letter?) would be 'a'.

I disagree.  If it's a 'large' building it presumably has more than one floor and it can be taken for granted that there is at least one staircase. It's not even necessary to explain that it 'leads to the upper floor'.

I don't think any of them is correct, just that 'a' sounds better than 'the' in this case.

Maybe the building has multiple staircases? In that case, 'the' would be incorrect, but 'a' is correct in every case.

This is not true. If there is only one staircase, then it is clear which staircase is meant by "the staircase", therefore it would be okay to use "the".

But right now we have no idea how many staircases there are.

@Supernerd411 The question clearly states that "there's only one staircase".

The reader has no idea

As one Dutch guy explained to me back in the 1990's, "the" means "this", while "a" means "any". This hint allows me to choose the proper article.

The narrator is most likely omniscient. In this case, the narrator knows that there is only one staircase leading to the floor above, so they would probably use "the". It may also be acceptable to use "a", but I would prefer "the".
If the narrator was not omnisient, for example it was Jack's friend Bob, then they would use whatever word they believe is most appropriate based on what they know or believe or assume to be the case.
It doesn't matter what the reader knows.
Suppose you had no idea of what your surroundings were, and you had your eyes closed. In this case, I could say "Look at the sheep", if I wanted you to look at the specific sheep that I knew was there. Alternatively, I could say "Look at a sheep", if I just wanted you to look at any sheep. It doesn't matter that you don't know what your surroundings are, I can use either phrase to convey whichever meaning I want.
After all, the speaker doesn't always know what the person listening knows, so they can't reliably change their speech to adjust for that fact.
Edit: my confidence in this answer has decreased, after realising that "He came across a monster. The monster spoke to him." Is more natural than another choice of articles, even though the narrator clearly knows that there is one monster, and to him, it is clear what monster he is talking about, which is something that my explanation fails to take into account. In this case, what matters isn't so much what the speaker knows or what the listener knows, but rather whether or not it is clear that the speaker is referring to. Because it is initially unclear what monster the speaker is referring to, initially "a" is used, but later, it is clear what monster the speaker is referring to, so "the" is used.
I have spent too long thinking about this and don't want to spend more time thinking about it, and am not confident that my answer is perfect, but also believe that my answer has potentially valuable information that I don't want to delete.
